# Переменные окружения [ .env files ]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .env, environment-variables

Например я ставлю библиотеку dotenv через npm или в React просто создаю переменную `REACT_APP_API_KEY=key` Файлы .env у нас в репозиторий мы не пушим, а приложению данные из этих файлов нужны. Каким образом такая информация передаётся другим участникам? Предположим нас несколько человека в команде. Как мне другому человеку передать данные env или как ему воспользоваться этими данными например `procces.env.PORT` если мы не пушим env файлы ?

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас нет полного окружения, которое вы шарите между разработчиками, обычно делают так:

1. Кладут в репозиторий файл и называют его, например `.env.example`. Важно что в нём не должно быть информации которую не хочется класть в репозиторий. Вся такая информация заменяется, например, на `CHANGE_ME`.
2. В ридми указывается что нужно скопировать содержимое `.env.example` в локальный файл `.env` и проставить нужные значения вместо `CHANGE_ME`
3. В зависимости от механизма публикации при сборке проекта для выката подкладывается нужный файл.

Поскольку в примере указана переменная `REACT_APP_`, я предполагаю что используется Create React App. Они поддерживают несколько файлов с переменными окружения, которые будут использваться в разных окружениях. Среди них есть `.env.development.local`, `.env.test.local` и `.env.production.local`. Их можно использовать чтобы для разных окружений переписывать значения из основных .env файлов.

- [Релевантная документация CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used)